# How to make two threads take turns in modifying an arraylist?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

The code you will see below is trying to achieve the following:

- add "line 0" into arraylist
- print the last item in the arraylist i.e. "line 0"
- remove last item from arraylist
- add "line 1" into arraylist
- print the last item in the arraylist i.e. "line 1"
  remove last item from arraylist

...and so on without end.

So, the output I expect is simply:

line 0

line 1

..

..

However, what I get is a random amount of "line i"s where i is also random.
Here's a sample output:

Line 0

Line 38919

Line 47726

Line 54271

then the program gets stuck in what appears to be a deadlock even though that doesn't make sense because the variable 'held' can only be true or false and either of those situations is supposed to allow one of the threads to do work.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

     static boolean held = true;
     static ArrayList<String> line = new ArrayList<>();


     public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int i = 0;
                while(true) {
                    if(held) {
                        line.add("Line " + i);
                        i++;
                        held = false;
                    }
                }
            }


        }.start();

        while(true) {
            if(!held) {
                System.out.println( line.get(line.size() - 1) );
                line.remove(line.size() - 1);
                held = true;

            }else continue;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: I ran this on ideone, and the output is as you expect it. So this must be some platform dependent issue. Try adding `volatile` to the held variable.

Comment: You can try and use a `Semaphore`

Comment: @ Martijn Courteaux making 'held' volatile did the trick, thanks!

Comment: This behavior is explained in [this section of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3).

Comment: @VGR "compilers are allowed to reorder the instructions in either thread, when this does not affect the execution of that thread in isolation" - now the behaviour of my program is explained, thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Likely the fact that your `held` variable is not `volatile` is causing the deadlock. The different cores on your computer will have their own memory caches, which are not necessarily updated concurrently. To make sure changes to held are visible to all threads, you should make it volatile. You could also use an AtomicBoolean, or synchronize access to the blocks of code.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is that in your main you are creating two different threads the first thread (the child) and the thread of the main that will deal with the while loop of the main. This means that you are running them at the same time so you can't be sure what is the value of ***held*** when each thread is using it. to solve this matter you have to use semaphore or mutex for accessing to ***held*** for change.

The second thing is that in your while loops there is nothing that makes the program out of them, that's why maybe it is causing you an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a lock object that both threads synchronize on, then have each thread do their action on the list, then use wait and notify to alternately wake up the other thread which would also do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think for this scenario it's better to use a **synchronized** **list** instead of arraylist:

```
List line = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList(...));
```